why overflow-wrap: break-word behave different with anywhere in table
I don't know why overflow-wrap: break-word; not working in table.
but overflow-wrap: anywhere; works.


table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
td {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    /* overflow-wrap: anywhere; */
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<div style="width: 600px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial
                MoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezumaMoctezuma
            </td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>




The only way I get break-word to wrap the string like anywhere is by adding a max-width declaration to td.
